# Twitter access token and access token secret have been changed automatically?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter4j

So I was running my code which involves getting past tweets from a list of twitter users (i'm using application based authentication). I have been running it for around 2 days and now, it throws me an exception,

> 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.

I then found that the access token and access token secret for my application at https://apps.twitter.com/ has been changed. [OAuth FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq) guide says "We do not currently expire access tokens" so I'm not sure what is really happening.

Below is the code snippet which does this (I'm using twitter4j library):

```
    private static void getTweetsOfTheseUsers( List<String> usernames )
    {
    Twitter twit = TwitterAuth.getInstance();
    for ( String user : usernames )
    {
        //get tweets for each user using twit.getUserTimeline();
    }
    }//end of method
```

**EDIT:**
I terminated the app and started again and it's working fine again with the same a/t and a/t/s. Can't really think what happned?